# multiple notificaition in gcm meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a simple query. I am implementing GCM notification in my application developed in meteor. The code goes as follows

```
    var gcm = Meteor.npmRequire('node-gcm');
    var sender = new gcm.Sender('MY_ID');
    var message = new gcm.Message();
    //message.addData('message',new Date().getTime());
    message.addData({'title':'mytitle','message':new Date().getTime()});
    message.delay_while_idle = true;
    var registrationIds = [];
    registrationIds.push("MY_REG_NO");
    sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Now when I call this method from client, I get a notification properly. But when I invoke this method again, the previous notification is overridden with the latest one. How can I show a list of notifications in the notification tray without overriding the previous ones?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should check your message variable to make sure you are actually declaring a new variable instead of just adding new texts to the already existing gcm.Message(). So, I'm guessing the idea is to always have a new message variable whenever you are adding new messages.

Comment: Done that, no effect!

Comment: Hey @larryp can u please elaborate a little. Havnt found any solution for this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found an answer to my own question. We need to add a notification id to the message.

Here is the complete solution.

```
var gcm = Meteor.npmRequire('node-gcm');
var sender = new gcm.Sender('MY_ID');
var message = new gcm.Message();
// message.addData('message',new Date().getTime());
message.addData({'title':'mytitle','message':new Date().getTime()});
message.delay_while_idle = true;
var registrationIds = [];
registrationIds.push("MY_REG_NO");
// YOU HAVE TO ADD THIS LINE
message.addData("notId", parseInt(Math.random() * 25));
sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```